# Save an iso of vmware fusion VM

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-fusion

I'm running VMWare Fusion and have an Ubuntu VM.  I've setup a ton of configurations and would like to save this to an ISO to deploy to a production environment.  Does anyone know if this is possible and what would be the best way to go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: I mean this in the nicest way, but you probably need to contract the heavy technical stuff with an IT consultant. If you do this stuff wrong because you don't understand it, you could easily LOSE all the information you're trying to work with.

Comment: Depending on your configuration, even a dd might work, but you DO want it to be done by someone who knows what he's doing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do it that way.

First, you [automate your Ubuntu installation using preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/appendix-preseed.html).

Then, you use a configuration management tool such as puppet or chef to manage the machines on an ongoing basis.

As for deploying the web application itself, doing this right tends to be highly app-specific, and you really haven't given enough detail to give a good recommendation.

Comment: Would this allow for copying all data? like `/var/www` content, apache with all sites, and other libraries I have installed?

Comment: Oh, you're the developer. Do you not have a system administrator to run the production system?

Answer (score 1):

[remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) in theory should let you create an initial installer ISO with the necessary bits. I'd probably use backup mode (which restores an identical system).

However, you can't actually install from it without a GUI (I usually install a lightweight DM (usually metacity) to the VM, run remastersys, then remove the DM after running the install). Its a rather hacky solution.

I'd *really* take Michael Hamton's advice about doing it the *right* way, and Adrian's advice of letting someone who understands the process well to do it. You don't want to end up with a hacked together, half broken system with too much wierdness.

Its worth doing once, well, and right.